# Python inner method cannot get variable from outer method

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

Code below:

```py
def cycle(f1, f2, f3):
    """Returns a function that is itself a higher-order function.

    >>> def add1(x):
    ...     return x + 1
    >>> def times2(x):
    ...     return x * 2
    >>> def add3(x):
    ...     return x + 3
    >>> my_cycle = cycle(add1, times2, add3)
    >>> identity = my_cycle(0)
    >>> identity(5)
    5
    >>> add_one_then_double = my_cycle(2)
    >>> add_one_then_double(1)
    4
    >>> do_all_functions = my_cycle(3)
    >>> do_all_functions(2)
    9
    >>> do_more_than_a_cycle = my_cycle(4)
    >>> do_more_than_a_cycle(2)
    10
    >>> do_two_cycles = my_cycle(6)
    >>> do_two_cycles(1)
    19
    """
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
    def execution(n):
        def inner(x):
            result = x
            while (n > 0):
                n = n - 1
                if (n >= 0):
                    result = f1(result)
                n = n - 1
                if (n >= 0):
                    result = f2(result)
                n = n - 1
                if (n >= 0):
                    result = f3(result)
            return result
        return inner
    return execution
```

run test in terminal

```sh
$ python -m doctest xx.py
```

get error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment
```

I think the `n` variable used in method `inner` can be got from outer method `execution`, as in runtime, `execution` must be first called to get `inner` method called, so the variable `n` must has been initialized. What mistake did I make here? It's `python 3.8.1` that I used.

Comment: Try using `nonlocal n` at the start of `inner`

Comment: @EdWard `nonlocal n` added to the first line of `inner`, the test command got stuck then. I have to use `ctrl +c` to terminate.

Comment: Maybe it's code problem, I'll check

Comment: @EdWard It do works

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The code as shown now won't throw the error. Did you change the goal of your question?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It does now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What has happened and why? Based on variable scope, you expect variable to be looked up in an outer scope (if not defined) and it indeed does work, try this:

```
def o(n):
    def i():
        print("now in inner", n)
    print("passed to outer", n)
    i()

o(42)
```

Now if you define a variable of the same name in an inner scope, it will (in that scope) shadow the variable in the outer scope, you can assign any value to it, you can access it, it all happens withing its scope:

```
def o(n):
    def i():
        n = "in"
        print("now in inner", n)
    print("passed to outer", n)
    i()
    print("back in outer", n)

o(42)
```

So why did you see `UnboundLocalError` exception? Because python will consider any variable local to it's scope if assigned to in that scope, if it's referred to prior to such assignment, it won't instead be accessed in the outer scope, but is considered not yet assigned locally:

```
def o(n):
    def i():
        print("now in inner", n)
        n = "in"
    print("passed to outer", n)
    i()
    print("back in outer", n)

o(42)
```

If you add [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) statement as suggested in the comments, the error goes away, because the variable is access the enclosing scope instead of being considered local, this however also means any changes / (re) assignments are affecting the outer scope as well and that (esp. in a larger program) can be surprising and confusing:

```
def o(n):
    def i():
        nonlocal n
        print("now in inner", n)
        n = "in"
    print("passed to outer", n)
    i()
    print("back in outer", n)

o(42)
```

To keep related bits closer together and relations explicit, it may be nicer to pass value of the variable to the inner function, perform whatever logic it is to perform and have it return the result:

```
def o(n):
    def i(inner_n):
        print("now in inner", n)
        inner_n += 1
        return inner_n
    print("passed to outer", n)
    print("i() returned", i(n))
    print("back in outer", n)

o(42)
```

---

To point to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#binding-of-names):

> The following constructs bind names: ... targets that are identifiers if occurring in an assignment ...
>
> If a name is bound in a block, it is a local variable of that block, unless declared as `nonlocal` or `global`.

Or as said, the assignment could be the last action in that block, but it means the variable is treated as local throughout (unless explicitly told not to).

Comment: Thanks your clear explanation. But if I pass variable `n` to the inner method, the convenience of higher-order function will lost. On other word, it makes less sense to define the inner function.

Comment: Yes, and in that case and noting impact inner function actions have on the outer function content, `nonlocal` would address the problem, and I hope the above post helps to also understand the mechanics as to how and why. I would however generally advice caution when traversing scopes and possible unforeseen impact thereof. Since your function both tries to modify n and has `return`s something, that may be ever more confusing. I would either expect "in-place" operation within immediately enclosing scope, or something that gets stuff in and returns results back.

Comment: You are right, there is no reason for me to write code like this in my example. Recently I learned closures, it seems like free variables are something in closures and closures do have it's place to use, so `"in-place" operation within immediately enclosing scope, or something that gets stuff in and returns results back` may not match all needs.